# Using context in an AsyncTask via a Fragment that has no UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have previously had my App working with just activities and am now working on converting to fragments in order to improve the UI.

Previously my `Activity` started an `AsyncTask` and passed in itself to be used as the `Context` when certain methods required it (not UI operations, but calls to shared preferences and content providers). I have now learnt that this approach can lead to undesirable outcomes if the `Activity` is destroyed and garbage collected, but it did compile and run fine.

I began this change because I wanted to make my loading screen behave better when the app was paused and stopped. I realised people frown on loading screens in Android but for me it is required as I have an operation that will take 20 seconds or so and that needs to be completed before the app will function.

So using [this guide](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2066699), I began improving my app.

In short the guide moves the `AsyncTask` into a `Fragment` that does not have [an attached UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding), with a separate `Fragment` for displaying the loading screen with `ProgressBar`. This means that the Fragment that spawns the `AsyncTask` does not have a Context, meaning I cant pass one in to the `AsyncTask`.

As I said before I have operations in the `AsyncTask` that require a `Context` object, so where can I get it from? Should I just pass in that data to the `AsyncTask` before I start?

Comment: The guide you link to handles this by passing the Activity in as a custom `ProgressListener` interface. Why can't you do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the context is not a static property, so you actually need one object to retrieve it.

Thus, you can either go the "hack-way" as in this post:

[Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

or you can follow Android guidelines and use a Service for your background loading. Remember that `AsyncTask` is an utility class designed to help in background operations that later need to communicate with the UI, so you should use `AsyncTask` in correlation with a UI object.
If you, instead use a `Service`, then you got no problem, since the `Service` object itself is the context that you need.

Comment: Great, I will create another service for this task. Although I now have a total of 7 services which seems excessive but I suppose thats another issue.

Comment: If it is a problem you can merge them into a single Service and use a value in the intent's bundle to describe the action to do in the service. I forgot to mention...since you were using AsyncTask, maybe you want to give IntentService a try. It is the framework implementation of a Service which uses an AsyncTask as its worker thread.

Comment: Having looked at this the same problem arises, assuming I want to start the service from the non-UI fragment I still need a context from which to create the Intent, as it is required in the constructor. Unless I can use one of the other intent constructors?

Comment: Ok...can you explain better why you can't use Fragment.getActivity()? The Fragment that starts the AsyncTask/Service has to be attached to an Activity or a ContextWrapper object!

Comment: This fragment is a non-UI fragment, that is it has no view and is not displayed. Read more about that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) , scroll down to "Adding a fragment without a UI".

Calling `getActivity()` returns null in this fragment.

My next plan is to explicitly set the context when I instantiate the `Fragment` in my main activity.

e.g.: `mInitFragment = new InitializeFragment();
    mInitFragment.setProgressListener(this);
    mInitFragment.setContext(this);
    mInitFragment.startLoading();`

Comment: It may also be sensible to pass in global context here?

Comment: Then, since it has no UI, shouldn't you use a Service INSTEAD of a Fragment. There is a particular reason you want to use a Fragment as a mere background worker? You need a synchronized lifecycle? Either way, if you still want to use the Fragment, passing the activity is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your AsyncTask is not handling any UI components you can use the parent Activity's context. So where you previously passed in `this` you'll now pass in `getActivity()`. Note, if you do have it changing the ui this will set you up for Null Pointer Exceptions.

Comment: I can't use `getActivity()` because it returns `null` when using a service that is not attached to a UI like this one is.